# Facebook login to web via native FB app

Tags: facebook, api, authentication

I have facebook login on my webpage [using php api] and wanted to ask, if is possible to open Native FB app on mobile devices to login to facebook and then redirect back to webpage.

Comment: No, that is not possible. There is no connection between the FB app and the browser that would make this possible.